# Magento add shipping the custom option for products

Tags: magento, size

I have add 3 size for the Magento Products using custom option

`4x5'4 , 5'4x7'8 ,7'8x 10`

I want different shipping for different size?

Is that possible?

Comment: i just wanted to know is that possible or not or i need to make a new extension?

Answer (score 1):

You can do one model extending Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract, and overrrides colectRates() methods, to check if this product return this, if that one return that.
See more here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module.

Or just change the magento core Mage shipping model carrier to do that.
Here's the hint:
You should take \app\code\core\Mage\Shipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate.php, and go to  collectRates function try something like that before put the ShippingPrice to method:

```
 foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {

            if ($item->getProduct()->getData('size') == "4x5'4"){
                $shippingPrice += 1.00;  
            }elseif()....
        }
```

Comment: Hello Guerra

Thanks for replay can you give me hint How i Can edit magento core Mage shipping model right now i have enable the **Flat Rate shipping per item $34**

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Guerra

I am able to solve this problem

I have add this function \app\code\core\Mage\Shipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate.php  to get the option

```
 function getProductOptions(&$item){  $options = array();  if ($optionIds = $item->getOptionByCode('option_ids')) {      $options = array();      foreach (explode(',', $optionIds->getValue()) as $optionId) {          if ($option = $item->getProduct()->getOptionById($optionId)) {
          $quoteItemOption = $item->getOptionByCode('option_' . $option->getId());

          $group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
              ->setOption($option)
              ->setQuoteItemOption($quoteItemOption);

          $options[] = array(
              'label' => $option->getTitle(),
              'value' => $group->getFormattedOptionValue($quoteItemOption->getValue()),
              'print_value' => $group->getPrintableOptionValue($quoteItemOption->getValue()),
              'option_id' => $option->getId(),
              'option_type' => $option->getType(),
              'custom_view' => $group->isCustomizedView()
          );
      }
  }  } if ($addOptions = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
  $options = array_merge($options, unserialize($addOptions->getValue()));  } return $options;}
```

Then I make a array for the size

```
foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $option =  $this->getProductOptions($item);
                foreach($option as $opt){
                    if($opt['value']=="5'4&quot; x 7'8&quot;"){
                        $shipExtra[] = '10.99';
                    }
                    else if($opt['value']=="7'8&quot; x 10'9&quot;"){
                        $shipExtra[] = '10.99';
                    }

                }
```

Then at the end I have

```
            $shipExtra = array_sum($shipExtra);
if($shipExtra!=""){
    $shippingPrice += $shipExtra;}
```

That works for me :)

Thanks to you for guiding me for the right file